# Drape multiple lines on a DEM with Postgis

Tags: postgis, dem, drape

I am trying to drape lines on a DEM by following this great tutorial:
http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/drape-lines-on-a-dem-with-postgis.html
When I do it on a single line by giving points coordinates it works perfectly:

```
WITH line AS
    -- From an arbitrary line
    (SELECT 'SRID=32632;LINESTRING (348595 4889225,352577 4887465,354784 4883841)'::geometry AS geom),
  linemesure AS
    -- Add a mesure dimension to extract steps
    (SELECT ST_AddMeasure(line.geom, 0, ST_Length(line.geom)) as linem,
            generate_series(0, ST_Length(line.geom)::int, 50) as i
     FROM line),
  points2d AS
    (SELECT ST_GeometryN(ST_LocateAlong(linem, i), 1) AS geom FROM linemesure),
  cells AS
    -- Get DEM elevation for each
    (SELECT p.geom AS geom, ST_Value(mnt.rast, 1, p.geom) AS val
     FROM mnt, points2d p
     WHERE ST_Intersects(mnt.rast, p.geom)),
    -- Instantiate 3D points
  points3d AS
    (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), val), 32632) AS geom FROM cells)
-- Build 3D line from 3D points
SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) FROM points3d;
```

However I am at a loss when it comes to applying the query to a whole table. The author mentioned that 'Your function would accept a parameter line, that you would use in the code! Just remove the WITH line AS part'
So the function would look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drape(line geometry) RETURNS geometry AS $$
.......

WITH linemesure AS (SELECT ST_AddMeasure(line, ...
```

But since there is no more temporary table (like line was before) I do not know what to select linemesure FROM.

Comment: What you have looks correct. You are simply replacing the first CTE that creates the linestring with the line parameter to the function. Have you tried running it?

Answer (score 1):

So just in case someone else encounters the same problem: this seems to work !

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drape(my_wkt text) RETURNS geometry AS $$
        DECLARE
            geom3d geometry;
        BEGIN
            WITH line AS
              (SELECT my_wkt::geometry as geom),
            linemesure AS
              -- Add a mesure dimension to extract steps
              (SELECT ST_AddMeasure(line.geom, 0, ST_Length(line.geom)) as linem,
              generate_series(0, ST_Length(line.geom)::int, 50) as i
              FROM line),
            points2d AS
              (SELECT ST_GeometryN(ST_LocateAlong(linem, i), 1) AS geom FROM linemesure),
            cells AS
             -- Get DEM elevation for each
              (SELECT p.geom AS geom, ST_Value(mnt2.rast, 1, p.geom) AS val
              FROM mnt2, points2d p
              WHERE ST_Intersects(mnt2.rast, p.geom)),
               -- Instantiate 3D points
            points3d AS
              (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), val), 2154) AS geom FROM cells)
             -- Build 3D line from 3D points
              SELECT ST_MakeLine(geom) INTO geom3d FROM points3d;
            RETURN geom3d;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;"""
```

where my_wkt is defined as:

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM my_table;
```